# Change the content of the page when changing the path of the current URL via pushState

Tags: javascript, html, url, browser-history, pushstate

I use some buttons(many of them), with modals attached and i changed the URL when entered the modal with the "pushstate".
I made it so when you`re leaving the modals the URL comes back to the initial one.

My problem is that when i use "back" and "forward" buttons, given by the browser, my URL changes, but my content doesn`t.

I tried using the "popstate" method but i really doesn`t know what am I doing wrong.

```
boxes.forEach(b => {
    let id = b.id;
    b.addEventListener('click', e => {
        history.pushState({id}, `Selected: ${id}`, `./selected=${id}`)
        selectBox(id);
    });
});

window.addEventListener('popstate', e => {
    selectBox(e.state.id);
});
```

I expected that when i press the "back" button(after i close the modal, so the history has changed) the content of the page will go back to the modal, and the URL will change too.

For now, just the URL it`s changed, not the content.

Comment: It depends. What happens in the `selectBox()` function?

Comment: `let boxes = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('box'));

          function selectBox (id) {
              boxes.forEach(b => {
                  b.classList.toggle('selected', b.id === id);
              });
          }`